# Form 'action' for form without GET or POST

Tags: html, forms

I have a 'form' that generates a url for a user via javascript. This is the HTML I have --

```
<form class="hidden profile-private-link-form">
    <span class="link">
        <input type="text" name="" value="<value>" />
    </span>
</form>
```

However, when I try and validate the HTML it says 'action need to be specified'. Is it fine to omit the action here, or what should I put instead?

Comment: Why intentionally leave out the `action="GET"` if that's what you want?

Comment: `action` is the URL that the form should submit to, it's the `method` which is `POST` or `GET`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, a form must have an action, which must specify a URL to submit data too. However, inputs, textareas, etc do *not* have to be contained within a form. If you can't actually submit the data (for whatever reason), then you shouldn't be using a form to enclose it, use a division.

If you're using AJAX or some form of JavaScript to submit data from the form, you should still specify an action as a fallback for those users who do not have JavaScript enabled.

Answer (score 0):

If you're validating, yes. See http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html ... according to the standard, action is required. Why are you validating?